# need to print response of a post request

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, post, request

This is my code and I am not able to print the response from a post reqquest that I am hitting. I can see the response in console but it doesnt get printed. I dont know how to do.

```
 var circleUrl ="..........my service.................";
    var circleName;
    var circleCode;
    var circleList='';

    var circleData;             
    $.ajax({
            url: circleUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('AUTHUSER', 'dshfgsjhgdksaj');
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
            },
            data : JSON.stringify({product:"abc", flag:"S"}),
            success: function(x) {
            try {
            if(x.statusCode=="000" && x.businessOutput.responseMsg=="SUCCESS") { 
            alert(x.businessOutput.webserviceResponse.circleData);
            temp = x.businessOutput.responseCode;   
            circleData= x.businessOutput.webserviceResponse.circleData;
            $.each(circleData, function(i, item) {

                    circleName = item.name;
                    alert(circleName);
                    circleCode = item.code;
                    circleList = circleList + "<li><a onclick='selectCircle(this);' href='javascript:void(0);' circle='"+circleName+"' circleId='"+circleCode+"'> &rsaquo;"+circleName+ "<span>&nbsp;</span></a></li>";
                        });
                } 
                }catch(err) {
                    console.log('error occur  :: '+err);
                }
            },
            error: function() {     }
        }); 

    document.getElementById("circlelist").innerHTML = "<div class='layout'><h1 class='head1 padding_right_5'><span><em class='service_white'> </em><strong class='arrow-right'></strong></span><strong>select circle</strong></h1><div class='layout shadow_01'><ul class='balanceInfo summaryTxt'><li class='box_shadow_none'>Select circle of your choice</li></ul><ul class='listBox'>"+circleList+"</ul><ul class='balanceInfo summaryTxt'><li class='align_center border_bottom_none'><a class='grey_btn margin_none width60' onclick='history.go(-1);return false;' href=''>back</a></li></ul></div></div></div>";
    }
```

Comment: if(x.statusCode=="200"

Comment: `x` is the data returned from the server, generally a string unless you specifiy JSON and get it parsed. Why would it have a statusCode and responseMsg. You seem to be using XMLHttpRequest syntax in jQuery ?

Comment: my service is such that it has a status code and response message

Comment: Is the `statusCode` header of type String?

Comment: Why don't you add `alert( typeof(x) )` as the first line in the success function, I'll bet you get `String`

Comment: {
  "statusCode": "000",
  "statusMessage": "Record Successfully Fetched",
  "dsStatusCode": "000",
  "dsStatusMessage": "Record Successfully Fetched",
  "businessInput": null,
  "businessOutput": {
    "productName": "dth",
    "webserviceResponse": {
      "circleData": [
        {
          "name": "Himachal Pradesh",
          "code": "101"
        },
        {
          "name": "Delhi NCR",
          "code": "102"
        },
        {
          "name": "Andhra Pradesh ",
          "code": "104"
        }
      ],
      "__hashCodeCalc": false
    }
  }
}

Comment: I am not able to parse and print it